# Copyright compliance for music used in a TV show

Tags: copyright, music, media, statutory-license

How do shows recorded and syndicated for replay on television (and comparable media) comply with the copyright of a music they play but do not own?

Comment: The answer is buried in law and regulations of [performance royalties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royalty_payment#Performance).